# Email Form File Upload Returns Files Empty

Tags: php, html, forms, input, encoding

This is a simple php email form that includes attachments. The form works correctly, except for the fact that when the files are uploaded for the attachments they upload yet there is no contents. I believe that means that the files being uploaded for attachments are not being properly decoded. Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
$action = $_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{
?>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="locate" id="locate ">
                <strong>Locate an Installer</strong>
            </label>
            <strong>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="become" id="become">Become an Installer
                </label>
            </strong>
        </p>
        <div class="left">
            Name:
            <div>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            Email:
            <div>
                <input name="mailfrom" type="text" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            Street:
            <div>
                <input name="street" type="text" id="street" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            City:
            <div>
                <input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            State:
            <div>
                <input name="state" type="text" id="state" size="10" /> Zip:
                <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" size="15" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            Country:
            <div>
                <input name="country" type="text" id="country" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            Phone:
            <div>
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>The fields above are REQUIRED<br>
            <strong>
                How did you hear about AirKrete<span style="font-size:11.0pt; ">®</span>? <br>Please make a selection.
                <span id="sprycheckbox1">
                    <span class="checkboxRequiredMsg"></span>
                </span>
            </strong>
        </p>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="friend" id="Connection_0">Friend</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="jobspec" id="Connection_1">Job Specification</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="hgtv" id="Connection_2">HGTV Promotion</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="web" id="Connection_3">Web Browsing</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="radio" id="Connection_4">Radio</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="tv" id="Connection_5">TV</label></div>
        <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="other" id="Connection_6">Other</label></div></p>
        <p class="clear-fix">&nbsp;</p>
        <div><p><strong>Comments:</strong><br></p></div>
        <p><textarea name="Comments" cols="43" rows="10" id="Comments"></textarea></p>
        <p><label>If you have Attachments....</label></p>
        <p><input name="file_attachment" type="file" size="30" /></p>
        <p>When completed please click Send Email Button</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="action" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.airkrete.com/airkrete_thankyou.php" /><p>Thank You</p>
    </form>
<?php 
} 
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{
    $locate = isset($_REQUEST['locate']) ? $_REQUEST['locate'] : "" ;
    $become = isset($_REQUEST['become']) ? $_REQUEST['become'] : "" ;
    $mailfrom = $_REQUEST['mailfrom'];
    $street = $_REQUEST['street'];
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state'];
    $zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
    $country = $_REQUEST['country'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $connection = $_REQUEST['Connection'];
    $comments = $_REQUEST['Comments'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
$filename = "uploads/".basename($_FILES['file_attachment']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_attachment"]["name"], $filename);
$file_size = $_FILES["file_attachment"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
$handle = fopen($filename, "a+");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    if ((($locate == "") && ($become == "")) || ($mailfrom == "") || ($street == "") || ($city == "") || ($state == "") || ($zip == "") || ($country == "") || ($phone == "") || ($name == ""))
    { 
        echo "Not all required forms were filled out, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
    else
    {   
        if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
        {      
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about become an installer and would also like to locate one. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        if($filename != ""){
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"http://airkrete.com/".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"http://airkrete.com/".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        $from = "From: $name<$mailfrom>\r\nReturn-path: $mailfrom"; 
        $subject = "Someone's interested in either finding an installer or becoming one!"; 
        mail("joseph.roberts@usa.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I could be completely wrong about why the files that are uploading are being uploaded blank but the encoding is an inkling.

I tried removing the following line:

```
    $content= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```

To no avail. Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of toying around with this I finally figured it out. I added a debugging feature and used the tmp_name instead initially. Although I don't see what exactly I changed that makes it work now, here's the working code that changed it.

```
        <?php 
} 
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{
    $locate = isset($_REQUEST['locate']) ? $_REQUEST['locate'] : "" ;
    $become = isset($_REQUEST['become']) ? $_REQUEST['become'] : "" ;
    $mailfrom = $_REQUEST['mailfrom'];
    $street = $_REQUEST['street'];
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state'];
    $zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
    $country = $_REQUEST['country'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $connection = $_REQUEST['Connection'];
    $comments = $_REQUEST['Comments'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));


  if(isset($_FILES['file_attachment'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['file_attachment']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['file_attachment']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['file_attachment']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['file_attachment']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file_attachment']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="Extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file. ";
  }

  if($file_size > 52428800){
     $errors[]='File size must be under 50 MB. ';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success! ";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
   }

    if ((($locate == "") && ($become == "")) || ($mailfrom == "") || ($street == "") || ($city == "") || ($state == "") || ($zip == "") || ($country == "") || ($phone == "") || ($name == ""))
    { 
        echo "Not all required forms were filled out, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
    else
    {   
        if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
        {      
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
        }
        else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about becoming an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
        }
        else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about locating an installer. My phone number is ".$phone.".\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "FROM: ".$name." <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
            $message .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
            $message .= "Located: ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "I would like to inquire about become an installer and would also like to locate one. My phone number is ".$phone.". I heard about you from: ".$connection."\r\n";
            $message .= "I also left the following comment:\r\n".$comments."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        if($file_name != ""){
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"http://airkrete.com/uploads/".$file_name."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"http://airkrete.com/uploads/".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        }
        $from = "From: $name<$mailfrom>\r\nReturn-path: $mailfrom"; 
        $subject = "Someone's interested in either finding an installer or becoming one!"; 
        mail("info@airkrete.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```